# More Optimal Method of Combining 100+ Images Together

Tags: python, python-3.4, python-imaging-library

Python3.4
PIL

I am combining 100+ 16x16 tiles together to randomly generate terrain for a test app and save as a .png file for storage.

My concern when testing is that I am receiving the following finish times:

- 100x100 map(1600x1600 pixel) = 1.16 minutes
- 200x200 map(3200x3200 pixel) = 2.43 minutes
- 300x300 map(4800x4800 pixel) = 5.27 minutes
- 500x500 map(8000x8000 pixel) = 13.14 minutes

For a mobile/desktop app, this is too long. Is there a more optimal of creating these maps?

Note: I do not plan to use anything other than 16x16 tiles. I am open to other Python modules however.

```
from datetime import datetime
from os import listdir, chdir
from random import randint
from time import strftime

from PIL import Image

x_size = 4800
y_size = 4800

x_tile_size = 16
y_tile_size = 16

x_tile_amount = int(x_size/x_tile_size)
y_tile_amount = int(y_size/y_tile_size)

new_im = Image.new('RGB', (x_size, y_size))

file_path = './assets/terrain/plains/'
print("Generating map.")
start_time = strftime("%H:%M:%S")
for i in range(x_tile_amount):
    for j in range(y_tile_amount):

    dice_roll = randint(1,7)

    if dice_roll == 1:
        terrain_file_path = 'grass_1.png'                        
    elif dice_roll == 2:
        terrain_file_path = 'grass_2.png'
    elif dice_roll == 3:
        terrain_file_path = 'grass_3.png'                            
    elif dice_roll == 4:
        terrain_file_path = 'grass_4.png'
    elif dice_roll == 5:
        terrain_file_path = 'white_flower.png'
    elif dice_roll == 6:
        terrain_file_path = 'red_flower.png'
    elif dice_roll == 7:
        terrain_file_path = 'blue_flower.png'

    old_im = Image.open(file_path + terrain_file_path)
    new_im.paste(old_im, (i*x_tile_size,j*y_tile_size))


end_time = strftime("%H:%M:%S")
t_format = "%H:%M:%S"
t_delta = datetime.strptime(end_time, t_format) - datetime.strptime(start_time, t_format)
print('Time to generate map = ' + str(t_delta))
new_im.save('pillow_test.png', 'PNG')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are loading each of your terrain images for each random choice. It would be better to preload all images and then simply use `random.choice()` to pick one of them for you, as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime
import random
from time import strftime

from PIL import Image

x_size = 4800
y_size = 4800

x_tile_size = 16
y_tile_size = 16

x_tile_amount = int(x_size/x_tile_size)
y_tile_amount = int(y_size/y_tile_size)

new_im = Image.new('RGB', (x_size, y_size))
file_path = './assets/terrain/plains/'
images = ['grass_1.png', 'grass_2.png', 'grass_3.png', 'grass_4.png', 'white_flower.png', 'red_flower.png', 'blue_flower.png']
terrain = [Image.open(os.path.join(file_path, image)) for image in images]

print("Generating map.")
start_time = strftime("%H:%M:%S")

for i in range(x_tile_amount):
    for j in range(y_tile_amount):
        old_im = random.choice(terrain)
        new_im.paste(old_im, (i*x_tile_size,j*y_tile_size))

end_time = strftime("%H:%M:%S")
t_format = "%H:%M:%S"
t_delta = datetime.strptime(end_time, t_format) - datetime.strptime(start_time, t_format)
print('Time to generate map = ' + str(t_delta))
new_im.save('pillow_test.png', 'PNG')
```

This approach should give you a huge speed up.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am now experiencing times of less than 10 seconds to do 500x500(8000x8000 pixel) map. Just like NinjaKitty's answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are opening a new Image n^2 times. That makes it extremely slow.

You should be preloading those images before you do your for loop

```
grass_1 = Image.open(file_path + 'grass_1.png')
grass_2 = Image.open(file_path + 'grass_2.png')
...
for i in range(x_tile_amount):
    for j in range(y_tile_amount):
         dice_roll = random.randint(1, 7)
         if dice_roll == 1:
              etc.
```

Another addition you could make is setting your pictures as a dict.

```
my_dict = {
    1: 'grass_1',
    2: 'grass_2',
    ...
}
```

Then you can just do

```
dice_roll = random.randint(1,7)
new_im.paste(my_dict[dice_roll], (i*x_tile_size,j*y_tile_size))
```

Try it out and see if that helps your time.

The main problem is that when you generate a 100x100 map, you're loading images 10,000 times. There's no reason to load the same 7 image files 10k times, so instead you just preload them and add as necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am now experiencing times of less than 10 seconds to do 500x500(8000x8000 pixel) map. Just like Martin's answer.